# AngularJS: extra 'style' element is being added to my div's, li's when using ng-show

Tags: angularjs, ng-show

AngularJS: I noticed an extra 'style' element is being added to my div's, li's when using ng-show...

My Code:

```
<li ng-class="{ active:TabPartnerGroup ===3 }"><a href ng-click="tab = 3; showPricelists(partnerGroup);">Price list</a></li>
```

HTML in browser:

```
<li ng-class="{ active:TabPartnerGroup ===3 }" class="active" style=""><a       href="" ng-click="tab = 3; showPricelists(partnerGroup);">Price list</a></li>
```

Where is *style=""* coming from? Can I get rid of it? Here's another example...

My code:

```
<div class="panel pricelist" ng-show="TabPartnerGroup === 3">
```

HTML in Browser:

```
<div class="panel pricelist" ng-show="TabPartnerGroup === 3" aria-hidden="false" style="">
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The ng-show, how it works.

Comment: *"Can I get rid of it?"* - you could, but it doesn't have any effect so why bother?

Comment: Thanks Bhojendra, I just checked the html on the example in angulars docs and looks like it's there also. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: what browser is this, I'm not experiencing this behavior in Chrome. (Looked at the docs linked above). Also it doesn't use the style tag to hide or display but uses classes. Even more interesting is why is it there with `ngClass` all that does is add classes. It doesn't have an `ngShow` attribute. As you can [see](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L172) it toggles the `ng-hide` class.

Comment: There's no **style** attribute in **IE** too.